# Multiple Aggregate functions in one request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data set which is the following:

```
{
  item: '123',
    array: [{
      array2:[{
        array3: [{
          property1: 1234
        }]
      }],
      anotherArray: [{
        property2: 1234
      }]
    }]
}
```

Im trying to aggregate sum of property2 and property one in the same request.
here is my current aggregate function:

```
Item.aggregate([
            {$match: {itemId: 1234}},
            {$unwind: "$array"},
            {$unwind: "$array.array2"},
            {$unwind: "$array.array2.array3"},
            {$unwind: "$array.anotherArray"},
            {$group: {
                _id: 0,
                property1: {$sum: '$array.array2.array3.property1'},
                property2: {$sum: '$array.anotherArray.property2'}

            }},
            {$project: {
                _id: 0,
                property1: "$property1",
                property2: "$property2",

            }},
        ], function (err, aggregate) {
            callback(null, aggregate);
        });
```

The problem is that the aggregates results of property one and two are always double the value they should be.

I guess the problem is with the $unwind of "anotherArray", because when i remove it I get the correct aggregation value.

Is it possible to make aggregation on multiple arrays with one aggregation function?

Currently im just making 2 different requests to the db with async parallel, but I want to make more complex aggregation in the future without making extra db calls.

Comment: Nested arrays are a **VERY BAD** idea

Comment: I'm having a very complex dataset with predefined structure I can't change much. So it is impossible to not use nested arrays here...

Comment: They really are a very bad idea if you're planning to query or aggregate with them, especially multiply nested like this. Would you at least explain to us what this data signifies and why it needs to be in such a suspect structure? What is the meaning of the sum? Could we make an auxiliary collection with a different structure and part of the data and use that to compute the sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution for my use case with MongoDB $setUnion.

Here is the code i used for my question:

```
Item.aggregate([
            {$match: { itemID: '1234'}},
            {$unwind: "$array1"},
            {$unwind: "$array1.array2"},
            {$project: {
                _id: 0,
                combined: {$setUnion: ['$array1.anotherArray', '$array1.array2.array3']},

            }},
            {$unwind: "$combined"},
            {$group: {
                _id: 0,
                property1: {$sum: '$combined.property1'},
                property2: {$sum: '$combined.property2'}
            }},
        ], function (err, aggregate) {
            cb(aggregate);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted the structure is not a good one and should probably be reviewed as to it's intent. It's really not clear why it is so structured or if anything else in the array's in either case could mess up the results here.

But there is a general approach when you have multiple arrays in a document, that is basically to treat each array separately and get your "totals" per document first. Then sum the totals from all documents afterwards:

```js
Item.aggregate([
    // Unwind only 1 inner array first
    { "$unwind": "$array" },
    { "$unwind": "$array.array2" },
    { "$unwind": "$array.array2.array3" },

    // Group back the sum of the element and the first of the other array
    // and only per document
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "property1": { "$sum": "$array.array2.array3.property1" },
        "anotherArray": { "$first": "$array.anotherArray" }
    }},

    // Unwind the other array
    { "$unwind": "$anotherArray" },

    // Group back the total and the first summed per document
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "property1": { "$first": "$property1" },
        "property2": { "$sum": "$anotherArray.property2" }
    }},

    // Total all documents and output
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "property1": { "$sum": "$property1" },
        "property2": { "$sum": "$property2" },
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "property1": 1,
        "property2": 1
    }}
],callback);
```

So by containing to only one array at a time and getting the totals only within the original document first you avoid the duplication problems of creating multiple copies for each unwound item of the other array. With discrete document totals it is then simple to get the overall totals from your required selection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but finally i found a simple solution for my usecase with $setUnion from mongodb

Comment: @scopsy I think the main point here was that you cannot actually "unwind"  two arrays at a time. The other case is that `$setUnion` can only work when your results are truly a "set" and all values are unique. Otherwise duplicates will be removed.